# How to use pre-built static library on ROS2 node

Tags: ros2, c++, ros-humble, colcon

I have .a file and header file (.h) for an SDK for a thermal sensor.
This is my package structure.

```
small_thermal
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── include
│   └── small_thermal
│       └── guideusbcamera.h
├── lib
│   └── libGuideUSBCamera.a
├── package.xml
└── src
    └── test_small_thermal.cpp
```

I want to use this library in a ROS 2 node, but I can't compile it using `colcon build`. How should I create the CMakeLists.txt file?

this is my cmakelist.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(small_thermal)

# Default to C99
if(NOT CMAKE_C_STANDARD)
  set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
endif()

# Default to C++17
if(NOT CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
endif()

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()


# ---------------------------------- 找套件 --------------------------------- #
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)
find_package(std_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(sensor_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(cv_bridge REQUIRED)
find_package(image_transport REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} /lib/libGuideUSBCamera.a)


target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}
  PUBLIC
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src>
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}_node /src/test_small_thermal.cpp)

install(
  DIRECTORY src/${PROJECT_NAME}
  DESTINATION include
)

install(
  TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
  EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME}Targets
  LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
  RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
  INCLUDES DESTINATION include
)

ament_package()
```

Comment: Thanks for posting a question. If relevant, or related, you could link back to the question that you initially posted this question under (as an answer), as reference. If that makes sense.